# Express/Node MDN Local Library Tutorial | Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Genre"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting a "Cast to ObjectId" error when executing the code for the Genre Detail Page of the Local Library Tutorial.

The MDN tutorial recommends using the following mongoose workaround on the "req.params.id" before calling the findById() method:

Using the following dependencies and imports:

```
node v16.17.0
"async": "^3.2.4",
"express": "^4.16.1",
"mongoose": "^6.5.3",

const Genre = require('../models/genre');
const Book = require('../models/book');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const async = require('async');
```

Adding my code below:

```
// Display detail page for a specific Genre.
exports.genre_detail = (req, res, next) => {
  const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
  async.parallel(
    {
      genre(callback) {
        Genre.findById(id).exec(callback);
      },

      genre_books(callback) {
        Book.find({ genre: id }).exec(callback);
      },
    },
    (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      if (results.genre == null) {
        // No results.
        const err = new Error('Genre not found');
        err.status = 404;
        return next(err);
      }
      // Successful, so render
      res.render('genre_detail', {
        title: 'Genre Detail',
        genre: results.genre,
        genre_books: results.genre_books,
      });
    }
  );
};
```

But I get a "BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer" when I implement the mongoose.Types.ObjectID() method.

Instead, I recently tried stringifying the "req.params.id" as follows.

```
// Display detail page for a specific Genre.
exports.genre_detail = (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id.toString();
  async.parallel(
    {
      genre(callback) {
        Genre.findById(id).exec(callback);
      },

      genre_books(callback) {
        Book.find({ genre: id }).exec(callback);
      },
    },
    (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      if (results.genre == null) {
        // No results.
        const err = new Error('Genre not found');
        err.status = 404;
        return next(err);
      }
      // Successful, so render
      res.render('genre_detail', {
        title: 'Genre Detail',
        genre: results.genre,
        genre_books: results.genre_books,
      });
    }
  );
};
```

But now I'm getting a "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Genre"" at the execution of the callback, according to the stack trace:

```
.exec(callback);
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?  I've spent at least 18 hours troubleshooting this and can't find a fix.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It's likely that `req.params.id` is not a valid mongoose id. Can you check its value at the beginning of the function?

Comment: can you please show your route for this?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for following up on this, much appreciated. I have finally resolved the issue.

So, to declare the 'Virtual' property in the Mongoose Schema, apparently you have to use the notation as explicitly laid out in the Mongoose docs.

I was using arrow function notation (which I generally prefer when writing JavaScript) as in the following:

```
/* Virtual for this genre instance URL. */
GenreSchema
  .virtual('url')
  .get( () => {
    return '/catalog/genre/'+this._id;
  });
```

The Mongoose docs use the following notation, where 'function' is spelled out:

```
/* Virtual for this genre instance URL. */
GenreSchema
  .virtual('url')
  .get(function () {
    return '/catalog/genre/'+this._id;
  });
```

The code doesn't work with arrow notation. Why?
The reason it's working with a traditional function but not with an arrow function is a tricky little property of arrow functions.

They don’t bind "this". Therefore “this” won’t be the `GenreSchema` inside the arrow function and `_id` can’t be found.

Thanks again for following up.